# Optimality guarantees of SGD convergence in Geometric Programming

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, geometric-programming

What guarantees of optimality do we get when minimizing with Stochastic Gradient Descent a problem in its original formulation, after showing that it is a Geometric Programming instance (i.e. can be formulated as Convex Optimization when applying logarithmic transformation to the variables)?

Comment: Cann you give more detail and context, please? And, without some connection to statistocs this would be better asked at math SE